# importing images from Google Drive to Colab

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory

```
import glob
import cv2

fake_img = []
images = glob.glob('/content/Hurricane_Sandy/fakes' + '/*.jpg')
for i in images:
    fake_img.append(i)
```

I'm using this code to import the `.jpg` files from my Google Drive and then add it to a list. But after this command, the list `fake_img` is still empty. Please let me know what mistake I'm doing in this.

Comment: Is your google drive mounted?